# where in LazyJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am new to Javascript and I am from c# background. I have been looking into utility javscript libraries and by going through lots of forums and posts, found this LazyJS library for array processing. I am trying to filter an array by applying some constraints (which in fact is a very basic) without any success. I am not sure what I am missing. I assumed it should be similar to the way we use these functional clauses in c#. For example,
Input array:

```
contents = [{ID: 1, ModuleID: 3},{ID: 2, ModuleID: 4},{ID: 3, ModuleID: 3}];

var result = Lazy(contents).where({ ModuleID: 3 });
console.log(result);
```

I expected it to log the result

```
[{ID: 1, ModuleID: 3},{ID: 3, ModuleID: 3}]
```

Instead I am getting this message getting logged in the browser

```
U {parent: k, filterFn: function, parent: undefined, filterFn: undefined,each: function…}
```

It is very strange as I have just followed the official documentation as in http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/docs/#Sequence-where . Could someone please point out the mistake I am doing or guide me to how to go about it? Also, is it possible to test these kind of things in JSFiddle or plunker and share it as I was not sure how to include this LazyJS library in JSFiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the author of Lazy.js and I have a C# background too! So I think I can help you :)

Let's take the equivalent in C#:

```
var result = from x in contents
             where x.ModuleID == 3
             select x;
```

In this example, `result` will be an `IEnumerable<T>`. It hasn't enumerated the original array (`contents`) yet. It won't actually do anything useful until you iterate over the result:

```
foreach (var res in result)
{
  Console.WriteLine(res.ModuleID);
}
```

The same is true for the `Lazy.Sequence` you get from Lazy.js. When you call `console.log(result)` you're seeing the internal properties of the *sequence* object (comparable to an `IEnumerable<T>`) rather than the actual iterated result.

To produce an array, you could call:

```
console.log(result.toArray());
```

Alternately, without creating an array to hold the contents of the sequence, you can iterate over it directly using `each`:

```
result.each(function(res) {
  console.log(res);
});
```

And yes, you can test out Lazy.js in JSFiddle. Just add it under "External Resources" (you can use the URL http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/javascripts/lib/lazy.js for the latest release, or alternately you could use https://rawgithub.com/dtao/lazy.js/master/lazy.js for master).

Here is a fiddle demonstrating your example:

http://jsfiddle.net/7U78H/

Answer (score 1):

```
contents = [{ID: 1, ModuleID: 3},{ID: 2, ModuleID: 4},{ID: 3, ModuleID: 3}];
var result = Lazy(contents).where({ ModuleID: 3 });
console.log(result.toArray());
                   ^^^^^^^^^
```

Note that `result` is not a plain array.  It is a Lazy object that would allow you to iterate over the results, further filter them, or perform other manipulations.  It doesn't perform its calculations to determine what the actual elements are until you need them (via iteration, `toArray()`, `take` or some such.)  Hence the name **Lazy**.  :-)

Comment: Beat to the punch, and by the expert!  :-)

Comment: But your answer is more concise :)